Trouble Creating Scheduled Task on Windows from .NET Core Application
I'm encountering an issue when attempting to create a scheduled task on Windows using a .NET Core application. Despite successfully building and running the executable, I can't find the task in the Task Scheduler. Here's my code:
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new TaskService object
            using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
            {
                // Create a new task
                TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();

                // Set task properties
                td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Cleanup Temporary Files and Flush DNS";

                // Create a trigger to run at system startup
                td.Triggers.Add(new BootTrigger());

                // Create a trigger to run at user logon
                td.Triggers.Add(new LogonTrigger());

                // Create actions (e.g., execute multiple commands)
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("cmd.exe", "/c del /Q /S %temp%\\*.* 2>nul", null)); // Commands to cleanup temporary files
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("cmd.exe", "/c del /Q /S %userprofile%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\INetCache\\*.* 2>nul", null));
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("cmd.exe", "/c del /Q /S %userprofile%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Temporary Internet Files\\*.* 2>nul", null));
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("cmd.exe", "/c ipconfig /flushdns", null)); // Command to flush DNS cache

                // Register the task in the root folder
                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("CleanupTask", td);

                Console.WriteLine("Task scheduled successfully.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    }
}

I've built the application for Windows x64 using dotnet build -r win-x64, but despite no apparent errors, the task isn't visible in the Task Scheduler after executing the .exe. Could someone help me identify what might be missing or suggest any troubleshooting steps? Thanks!
